# Сравнение строки и указателя на строку в C

Tags: c, указатели

Я написал функцию my_strcat, которая дописывает в конец строки s1 строку s2:

```
char *my_strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2) 
{
    char *s1_ptr = s1;
    while (*s1_ptr != '\0')
    {
        s1_ptr++;
    }
    while (*s2 != '\0')
    {
        *s1_ptr = *s2;
        s1_ptr++;
        s2++;
    }
    *s1_ptr = '\0';
    return s1;
}
```

Для тестировки корректности работы функции я хочу вызвать assert:

```
int test_strcat(){
    char s1[] = "United";
    char s2[] = "States";
    assert(my_strcat(s1, s2) == "UnitedStates");
}
```

Вроде бы всё должно работать правильно, но assert постоянно выдаёт ошибку. Думаю, что я где-то напортачил с указателями и из-за отсутствия опыта работы с ними не могу разобраться. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: "но assert постоянно выдаёт ошибку" - Никогда! не говорите какую ошибку "выдаёт assert". Мы угадаем ее сами.

Comment: Комментарий по поводу того, почему я думаю, что это должно работать. Как я понимаю, строка однозначно определяется указателем на ячейку памяти, в которой находится первый символ этой строки. Значит можно передать в сравнение именно указатель

Comment: Assertion просто пишет, что он свалился. 
test_strcat: Assertion `my_strcat(s1, s2) == "UnitedStates"' failed.

Comment: *Да, вы пишете в память, которая не была выделена в `s1[]`*. Но, `assert()` падает не из-за этого, а потому что вы хотите сравнить содержимое, а фактически **сравниваете адреса** `s1[]` и константы `"UnitedStates"` (очевидно, что они разные). На самом деле вам надо (исправив ошибку с памятью) написать `assert(strcmp(my_strcat(s1, s2), "UnitedStates") == 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То есть я уже угадал. К assert-у это не имеет никакого отношения. Когда Вы дошли до конца `s1` и  начинаете дописывать `*s1_ptr = *s2;` - в какую память это пишется?

---

> Значит можно передать в сравнение именно указатель

Ну вот Вы и сравнили указатели. Они одинаковые?

[strcmp](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp)

Comment: Запись начинается в ячейке памяти, где находится '\0' у строки s1.
т.е если у нас хранилось [a] [b] [0] [c] [d] [e] [0],  то после начала записи у нас будет [a] [b] [c] [c] [d] [e] [0]. Как я понимаю

Comment: Да, действительно разные, что-то я не подумал про это) Значит в assert здесь нужно задействовать именно strcmp?

Comment: @HeartMarshall Вы можете задействовать что хотите. Но то, что в вопросе, не делает то, что Вы думаете.

Comment: @HeartMarshall Повторю вопрос: ... начинаете дописывать *s1_ptr = *s2; - в какую память это пишется?

Comment: Хм, судя по всему в ту память, которая не зарезервированна под s1. Ошибку понял

Comment: @HeartMarshall Отлично. День прошел не зря.

Answer (score 0):

А на каком основании Вы считаете, что Ваш код должен работать правильно?

Если Вы не выделяете дополнительной памяти в s1 под копирование чаров из s2.

После того, как вы нашли '\0' в s1 - память в s1 закончилась и все что за этим '\0' - Вам не принадлежит. Вы пишите в область памяти, которую вы не выделяли.

Comment: Прямо скажем, `assert()` (о чем спрашивает ТС) падает не из-за этого